# How to override the H2 with embedded postgreSQl lib in unit testing?

Tags: corda

In unit testing for Corda, it runs a H2 DB. Given that I run a postgreSQL in production, I would like to run using PostgreSQL during unit testing to close this gap (rather than leave it to integrating testing) as well. There are embedded postgreSQL lib to "mock" postgreSQL".

How can i override the default H2 DB in Corda to run a embedded postgreSQL instead during unit testing?

Answer (score 2):

Short Answer: You will not be able to customize the default database for unit testing.

The reason is that the unit test uses Mock Network service. And currently, H2 is the default database at the moment.

PS: But we have thought about tooling for a customized database for testing.